# Does Daruk's Protection absorb damage?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm really bad at deflecting attacks, so I just use Daruk's Protection to deflect them, but I noticed that when I use it to deflect guardian beams, but it didn't kill a STATIONARY guardian! (the rusted ones, not the turrets) Why? Do I need to do some kind of absurd flurry rushing/shield parrying training? Other random stuff I had: master sword, near hyrule castle, Savage lynel shield, (I forgot the bow) and had no buffs.

Comment: Also, I got all divine beasts, full stamina wheel, 15 hearts, no yellow hearts or yellow stamina

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daruk's Protection does not reflect damage, and cannot be used to kill a guardian.

To kill a guardian, you need to do one of the following:

- Do a perfect parry with your shield against the guardian's laser attack. If the guardian is capable of walking around, you will need to do this multiple times. If your timing is less than perfect, this may also use up a hit on Daruk's Protection. If you're feeling brave, you can disable Daruk's Protection in the "key items" section of your inventory to prevent this from happening. However, this will make it harder to parry because Daruk will no longer be fixing your mistakes for you.

  - Guardians make a "beep" noise right before they shoot. If you parry right after the beep, with a little practice, you should be able to successfully parry most laser attacks.
- Wield an Ancient Shield, and block the guardian's laser attack with it. It will reflect automatically, without requiring a parry. This consumes durability, unlike parrying. You can acquire an Ancient Shield from the Akkala Ancient Tech Lab in exchange for rupees and ancient parts.

  - This does not work with the "regular" shields you get from the combat trials and other mini-guardian enemies. You have to purchase the shield from Robbie's lab.
- Shoot the guardian with an ancient arrow. Unlike all other enemies, guardians will still drop loot if killed in this manner. Ancient arrows can be found as rare loot or purchased from Robbie's lab.
- Just keep shooting the guardian's eye with non-ancient arrows, or hitting it with ordinary attacks, until its HP is depleted. This takes a while and can be riskier than the other methods.
- Use Urbosa's Fury to damage and stun the guardian.

Comment: Daruks protection can be used to parry attacks. If you miss the perfect parry Daruks protection will use a charge instead to parry the attack. So it's good for protecting yourself from guardian attacks. Though it can get annoying since it does this for ANY attack.

Comment: I just use the master sword to chop off all the legs, and while its stunned, kill it. I just needed this for the guardian turrets, because they can't be stunned except for an arrow to the eye.

Comment: Just a small note, on masters mode the guardians can 'hold' their beam for a split second before shooting to throw your parry timing off.

Comment: WHAT?!?!? Oh boy... Just another reason to not to try master mode... UPDATE: I just got Mipha's Grace+, and my shield parrying got better :)

Comment: Guardian swords and ancient swords are also useful for immobilizing guardian stalkers: they always sever the legs with a single strike, whereas other weapons may require multiple strikes. Ancient armor purchased from the tech lab (and some other special gear you may find) is also useful for guardian combat.

Comment: I just tested it, and daruk's protection deflects the laser right back. You can even parry inside it!                              EDIT: Do you mean that it doesn't reflect PURE damage? Because you can't deal damage except for the lynel shields.